# How get recurse knapsack problem with best solution?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

I try to write simple 01 knapsack problem with recurse method,the optimal value is fine, but optimal solution in recurse method confused me in the funtion, so how to re-write `y` can let it correct?

```py
def recurseKnapsack(w, v, i, j, c, n, y):
    if i == n - 1:
        if j < w[i]:
            optvalue = 0
            y[i] = 0
        else:
            optvalue = v[i]
            y[i] = 1
        return optvalue

    if j < w[i]:
        y[i] = 0
        optvalue = recurseKnapsack(w, v, i+1, j, c, n, y)
    else:
        tmp1 = recurseKnapsack(w, v, i+1, j, c, n, y)
        tmp2 = recurseKnapsack(w, v, i+1, j - w[i], c, n, y) + v[i]
        if tmp1 > tmp2:
            optvalue = tmp1
            y[i] = 0
        else:
            optvalue = tmp2
            y[i] = 1

    return optvalue



w  = [2, 2, 6, 5, 4]
v  = [6, 3, 5, 4, 6]
c = 10

y = np.zeros_like(w)
optvalue = recurseKnapsack(w, v, 0, c, c, len(w), y)
print("optValue", optvalue, y)
```

> optValue 15 [1 1 0 0 0]

Comment: `y` shows that three first items have been used to get 14. It seems right, does it?

Comment: if set `w  = [2, 2, 6, 5, 4] v  = [6, 3, 5, 4, 6] c = 10`, the `y` is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you are using the same `y[]` in all recursive branches, so some branch **after** the best solution rewrites the record about it.

Consider the next code (not well tested). Function returns tuple of the best value and list of used indices:

```
 def recurseKnapsack(w, v, i, j, c, n):
    if i == n - 1:
        if j < w[i]:
            return (0, [])
        else:
            return (v[i], [i])

    without = recurseKnapsack(w, v, i+1, j, c, n)
    if j >= w[i]:
        t = recurseKnapsack(w, v, i+1, j - w[i], c, n)
        if t[0] + v[i] > without[0]:
            return (t[0] + v[i], [i]+t[1])
    return without

   >> optValue (15, [0, 1, 4])
```

Comment: Thanks My Russia Friends,Recently I am busy at learning math,so had forgot here.